# Autolayout - Make superview height equal to subview height + constant where subview is textView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a `UIView` and inside the `UIView` I have a `UITextView`. The `UITextView` does not scroll, instead I set it `programmatically` to its full height with the following line of code :

```
self.textView.sizeToFit()
```

Through the interface builder, I set the following `constraints` for the `UITextView` , including `superView.bottom = textView.bottom + 25` :

[image: Constraints for textView]
[image]

But then this is the result that I get when I run the app :

[image: result]

If anybody has any idea how could I fix this to fit the whole 'extended' `textView`, that would be really appreciated if you could let me know. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason it's a text view instead of a label?

Comment: I thought so but now that I think about it I think a label might work too as long as it has multiple lines and dynamic height. The fact is that I don't know how much text there's gonna be, so do you think a label could work too? @Wain

Comment: Can you post whole view controller and it's constraints ? It is depends on other constrains also.

Comment: Is the text field's super view's height constant or changeable? Because you set both height constraints and top, bottom space constraints for the text field,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a label instead of a text view. The important difference is that a label has an intrinsic content size where as a text view doesn't (because it's intended to scroll its content). This allows the label to work with the constraint system to display all of the text (without you needing to calculate the size).

If you stay using the text view you should add a height constraint and calculate the required height and configure the constraint appropriately.

Comment: Thanks that sounds right! I switched to a UILabel but now [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WlJ7E.png) is what I get : 
  . I set the bottom constraint to the superView and the height to be >= than a constant. Any ideas? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: don't use >= basically ever, and you don't need a height constraint, if you want padding add it on the edge constraints

Comment: Okay, I'll try  removing it then! I put just because I wanted a minimum height of the superview.

Comment: Removing it doesn't change much unfortunately. I tried and it still has the minimum height but it stays fixed. [These](http://i.stack.imgur.com/002cr.png) are the constraints that there are on the UILabel. Could it be the fact that I change the content of the UILabel in ViewDidLoad() ? It's initialized with a value and then updated with another value. Meaning do I have to somehow update the constraints?

Comment: it's probably a good idea to ask for a layout update after you change the content

Comment: Excuse my ignorance; do you know if there's a function for that? Or do I just programmatically create a new constraint?

Comment: call `layoutIfNeeded` on the view

Comment: I did but unfortunately nothing changed. I think it might be still a constraints problem as even in the interface builder the text I set as default on the UILabel should be longer, therefore expand the superView. But it doesn't, not it shows the dotted yellow lines meaning that I need to update the frame. It kind of looks like if there's a fixed width set somewhere but I can't find any.  [These](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SWDar.png) are all the constraints I have for my UILabel and [these](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xZKK8.png) are all the ones I have for its superView. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: Thanks again for the help by the way, much appreciated.

Comment: I figured it out, it was the "alignbottomto : View" thanks!